# PHP send mail form, working - but send an empty mail at page refresh

Tags: php

I'm an ASP.NET user, but want to learn PHP, I have made a PHP mail send form and it's made from some tutorials from the net, search by google.

I have one...no two questions.

1. When I load the page, it send an empty mail to me, why ?
2. Is there something you will recommend that I use or edit in my code ?

My working code is this

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {
//START of validation 
    // Initialize error array.
    $errors = array();
    // Check for a proper name
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['navn'])) {
        $navn = $_REQUEST['navn'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$navn)){ $navn = $_REQUEST['navn'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Dit navn kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast dit navn.';}

    //Check for a valid phone number
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['telefon'])) {
        $telefon = $_REQUEST['telefon'];
        $pattern = "/^[0-9\_]{7,20}/";
        if (preg_match($pattern,$telefon)){ $telefon = $_REQUEST['telefon'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Dit telefon nummer kan kun være tal.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast dit telefon nummer.';}

    // Check for a proper info
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['beskrivelse'])) {
        $beskrivelse = $_REQUEST['beskrivelse'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$beskrivelse)){ $beskrivelse = $_REQUEST['beskrivelse'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Din beskrivelse kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en beskrivelse.';}

    // Check for a proper value
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['mvalue'])) {
        $mvalue = $_REQUEST['mvalue'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$mvalue)){ $mvalue = $_REQUEST['mvalue'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Feltet mængde kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en mængde.';}

    // Check for a proper comment
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['kommentar'])) {
        $kommentar = $_REQUEST['kommentar'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$kommentar)){ $kommentar = $_REQUEST['kommentar'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Din kommentar kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en kommentar.';}
 }
//End of validation 

//START Send mail
    if (empty($errors)) { 
        $to = "my@mail.dk"; 

        $message = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
        $message .= "<html><head></head><body>";
        $message .= "<table>";
        $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $navn . " har sendt denne foresp&oslash;rgsel.</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Telefon nr.:</td><td>" . $telefon . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Beskrivelse:</td><td>" . $beskrivelse . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>M&aelig;ngde:</td><td>" . $mvalue . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Kommentar:</td><td>" . $kommentar . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table></body></html>";
        $message .= trim(stripslashes($message));

        $subject = "Mosegården Forespørgsel fra " . $navn . ".";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Mosegården Hjemmeside - Forespørgsel" . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
//End of Send mail
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
        input[type=text] {
            padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        input[type=text]:focus {
            border-color:#333; 
        }
        input[type=submit] {
            padding:5px 15px; 
            background:#ccc; 
            border:0 none;
            cursor:pointer;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px; 
        }
        textarea{
            padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Foresp&oslash;rgsel</h1> 
        <div id='emailerror'>
                <?php 
                //Print Errors
                if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {
                // Print any error messages. 
                    if (!empty($errors)) { 
                        echo '<hr /><h3>Der skete følgende:</h3><ul>'; 
                        // Print each error. 
                        foreach ($errors as $msg) { echo '<li>'. $msg . '</li>';}
                        echo '</ul><h1>Mail ikke send! pga. følgende fejl.</h1><hr />';
                    } else {
                            echo '<hr /><h1 style="color:#00ff00;">Mail Send!</h1><hr />'; 
                    }
                }
                //End of errors array
                ?>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Navn:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="navn" value="<?php echo $navn; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Telefon nr.:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="telefon" value="<?php echo $telefon; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Beskrivelse:</label>
                </div> 
                <textarea name="beskrivelse"><?php echo $beskrivelse; ?></textarea>
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>M&aelig;ngde:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="mvalue" value="<?php echo $mvalue; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Kommentar:</label>
                </div> 
                <textarea name="kommentar"><?php echo $kommentar; ?></textarea>
            </div> 
            <br />
            <input name="submitted" type="submit" value=" Send " />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the email sending code inside `if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted']))` since when the page is loaded the email code is executed, so to make sure that the email is send when you submit you need to put the code inside the block `if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted']))`

Comment: You got Sending mail code outside the `(isset($_REQUEST['submitted']))`

Comment: It sends an empty email because of your conditional statement `if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted']))` and the bracing for it. Everything outside that will be executed. There, you've 3 comments saying *basically* the same thing, in so many words ;-)

Comment: I suggest including validation for `isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])` in your `$errors` array, or moving the send email part inside the first `if`

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty - will you give me an answer so I can close this topic/thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I moved the closing bracket from the if statement on line 2 to the bottom of your send mail routine. See comments on line 78

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {
//START of validation 
    // Initialize error array.
    $errors = array();
    // Check for a proper name
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['navn'])) {
        $navn = $_REQUEST['navn'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$navn)){ $navn = $_REQUEST['navn'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Dit navn kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast dit navn.';}

    //Check for a valid phone number
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['telefon'])) {
        $telefon = $_REQUEST['telefon'];
        $pattern = "/^[0-9\_]{7,20}/";
        if (preg_match($pattern,$telefon)){ $telefon = $_REQUEST['telefon'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Dit telefon nummer kan kun være tal.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast dit telefon nummer.';}

    // Check for a proper info
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['beskrivelse'])) {
        $beskrivelse = $_REQUEST['beskrivelse'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$beskrivelse)){ $beskrivelse = $_REQUEST['beskrivelse'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Din beskrivelse kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en beskrivelse.';}

    // Check for a proper value
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['mvalue'])) {
        $mvalue = $_REQUEST['mvalue'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$mvalue)){ $mvalue = $_REQUEST['mvalue'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Feltet mængde kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en mængde.';}

    // Check for a proper comment
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['kommentar'])) {
        $kommentar = $_REQUEST['kommentar'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ\_]{2,20}/";// This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern,$kommentar)){ $kommentar = $_REQUEST['kommentar'];}
        else{ $errors[] = 'Din kommentar kan kun indholde _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'Venligst indtast en kommentar.';}

//End of validation 

//START Send mail
    if (empty($errors)) { 
        $to = "my@mail.dk"; 

        $message = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
        $message .= "<html><head></head><body>";
        $message .= "<table>";
        $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $navn . " har sendt denne foresp&oslash;rgsel.</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Telefon nr.:</td><td>" . $telefon . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Beskrivelse:</td><td>" . $beskrivelse . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>M&aelig;ngde:</td><td>" . $mvalue . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td>Kommentar:</td><td>" . $kommentar . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table></body></html>";
        $message .= trim(stripslashes($message));

        $subject = "Mosegården Forespørgsel fra " . $navn . ".";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Mosegården Hjemmeside - Forespørgsel" . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
//End of Send mail
 } // <-- moved bracket to here to close if statement on line 2
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
        input[type=text] {
            padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        input[type=text]:focus {
            border-color:#333; 
        }
        input[type=submit] {
            padding:5px 15px; 
            background:#ccc; 
            border:0 none;
            cursor:pointer;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px; 
        }
        textarea{
            padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Foresp&oslash;rgsel</h1> 
        <div id='emailerror'>
                <?php 
                //Print Errors
                if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {
                // Print any error messages. 
                    if (!empty($errors)) { 
                        echo '<hr /><h3>Der skete følgende:</h3><ul>'; 
                        // Print each error. 
                        foreach ($errors as $msg) { echo '<li>'. $msg . '</li>';}
                        echo '</ul><h1>Mail ikke send! pga. følgende fejl.</h1><hr />';
                    } else {
                            echo '<hr /><h1 style="color:#00ff00;">Mail Send!</h1><hr />'; 
                    }
                }
                //End of errors array
                ?>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Navn:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="navn" value="<?php echo $navn; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Telefon nr.:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="telefon" value="<?php echo $telefon; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Beskrivelse:</label>
                </div> 
                <textarea name="beskrivelse"><?php echo $beskrivelse; ?></textarea>
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>M&aelig;ngde:</label>
                </div> 
                <input type="text" name="mvalue" value="<?php echo $mvalue; ?>" />
            </div> 
            <br />
            <div> 
                <div class="input_label user"> 
                    <label>Kommentar:</label>
                </div> 
                <textarea name="kommentar"><?php echo $kommentar; ?></textarea>
            </div> 
            <br />
            <input name="submitted" type="submit" value=" Send " />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```